# Adding blender cloths to a make human model

Tags: modeling, mesh, materials

I have added cloths in blender to a model imported from Make Human.
I linked it with the rig on the make human model using automatic weighting.

Normally it is alright:

[image]

But in some cases the model shows though the cloths:

[image]

Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you select the bone for the upper half of the arm, then edit the weightpaint map, in Weight Paint Mode (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>, while in object mode), such that the parts that are not supposed to be affected by the bone are blue.

Comment: Shift+tab in edit mode toggles snapping. I fail to see how this helps the OP?

Comment: I meant object mode

Comment: i think someonewithpc means "Weight Painting"

Comment: That's still for snapping.. Did you mean Ctrl+Tab?

Comment: @gandalf3 Yes, mistakes had been made....